# c# is there a method to serialize to UrlEncoded?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, serialization, urlencode

I want to use facebook's API and i find it hard to convert objects to urlEncoded.
so, for now i have something like:

```
string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);

            postData = postData.Replace(@"\", "");
            postData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postData);

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            string facebookUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/";
```

problem is that facebook doesn't accept jsons but UrlEncoded data, as it seems, correct me if im wrong.

So, Im pretty sure converting objects to UrlEncoded string is impossbile in .Net 4.5.1 because I've tried to use some of the answers for this questions that are while ago they are not working for me.

for example:

```
var result = new List<string>();
            foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(req))
            {
                result.Add(property.Name + "=" + property.GetValue(req));
            }

            postData = string.Join("&", result);
```

but `.Name` and `.GetValue` aren't defined at all.

Would like to get some help with that, TIA.

Objects i use:

```
internal sealed class FacebookValidationRequest
{
    public string access_token;
    public fbReq[] batch;
    public string method;
    public string format;
    public int pretty;
    public int suppress_http_code;
    public string debug;

    public FacebookValidationRequest(string appId, string userToken)
    {
        access_token = userToken;
        batch = new[]
        {
            //test code
            new fbReq("GET", "me"),
            new fbReq("GET", "me/friends?limit=50") //,
            //new fbReq("GET", "app?access_token=" + userToken)
        };
        method = "post";
        format = "json";
        pretty = 0;
        suppress_http_code = 1;
        debug = "all";
    }

}

internal sealed class fbReq
{
    public string method;
    public string relative_url;

    public fbReq(string m, string url)
    {
        method = m;
        relative_url = url;
    }
}

FacebookValidationRequest req = new FacebookValidationRequest(appToken, userToken);
```

Also, took the token for the  [facebook debugger site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

how facebook wants to object to look like after encoding:

> access_token=mytoken&batch=%5B%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%22me%22%7D%2C%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%22me%2Ffriends%3Flimit%3D50%22%7D%5D&debug=all&fields=id%2Cname&format=json&method=post&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1

Comment: Actual url encoding of the properties should be done with `System.web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String str)`. For the rest, um, not sure what you're trying to do. Just feed it the properties it requires manually? Why are you bothering with json if json is not what it uses?

Comment: @Nyerguds mostly because i want to make changes in the future and i dont want to write the params everytime, want something to build the encoded string automagically :)

Comment: Would be handy to see how the class of that `req` object is actually defined in terms of attributes on the properties.

Comment: @Nyerguds you got it

Comment: Um. None of that makes any sense at all. You don't need to serialize anything there; the class simply contains a property which _is_ your url-encoded request, namely `relative_url`.

Comment: im sorry, i didnt get you.

Comment: If you were url encoding a class I'd expect a class with an int property called "limit" set to "50", which then gets transformed to "?limit=50". That's what url encoding _is_; just pasting the parameters onto the url.

Comment: look at my edit in the end of the question.

Comment: Wow, ugly. But I see what you're trying to do now, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that the easiest way to do this is with Attributes to describe your properties, just like how the .Net Json's `DataContract` system does it. Basically, you assign an attribute to each property you want serialized, and make that attribute contain the name to serialize it as. I don't think you want to get into the mess of actually writing your own DataContractSerializer, though, so it might be easier to simply create your own Property class and a simple serializer using reflection.

The attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class UrlEncodeAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public UrlEncodeAttribute(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then, to apply to your data class... put the attributes on all properties:

```
internal sealed class FacebookValidationRequest
{
    [UrlEncodeAttribute("access_token")]
    public String AccessToken { get; set; }
    [UrlEncodeAttribute("method")]
    public String Method { get; set; }
    [UrlEncodeAttribute("format")]
    public String Format { get; set; }
    [UrlEncodeAttribute("pretty")]
    public Int32 Pretty { get; set; }
    [UrlEncodeAttribute("suppress_http_code")]
    public Int32 SuppressHttpCode { get; set; }
    [UrlEncodeAttribute("debug")]
    public string Debug { get; set; }

    public fbReq[] Batch { get; set; }

    [UrlEncodeAttribute("batch")]
    public String BatchString
    {
        get
        {
            // put your json serialization code here to return
            // the contents of Batch as json string.
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, `Batch` does *not* have the `UrlEncodeAttribute`, while its string representation `BatchString`  *does*. Its `get` is what will be called by the serializer, so you can put the conversion code in there.

Also note that thanks to the text names you give in the attributes, your properties don't need to have the names you actually get in the serialization, which looks *much* cleaner in my opinion. C#'s own serialization to xml and json works in the same way.

Now, let's take a look at the actual serialization, using reflection to get those properties:

```
public static String Serialize(Object obj, Boolean includeEmpty)
{
    // go over the properties, see which ones have a UrlEncodeAttribute, and process them.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {
        object[] attrs = p.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (Object attr in attrs)
        {
            UrlEncodeAttribute fldAttr = attr as UrlEncodeAttribute;
            if (attr == null)
                continue;
            String objectName = fldAttr.Name;
            Object objectDataObj = p.GetValue(obj, null);
            String objectData = objectDataObj == null ? String.Empty : objectDataObj.ToString();
            if (objectData.Length > 0 || includeEmpty)
            {
                objectData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(objectData);
                objectName= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(objectName);
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                    sb.Append("&");
                sb.Append(objectName).Append("=").Append(objectData);
            }
            break; // Only handle one UrlEncodeAttribute per property.
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

A more advanced version of this could be made by including a serialization method property in the UrlEncodeAttribute class (probably best done with an enum), so you can simply specify to serialize the array on the fly using json. You'll obviously need to put the actual json converter into the Serialize function then. I thought using the getter on a dummy property as preparation method was simpler, here.

Obviously, calling it is simply this: (assuming here the `Serialize()` function is in a class called `UrlEncodeSerializer`)

```
FacebookValidationRequest fbreq = new FacebookValidationRequest();
// fill your data into fbreq here
// ...

// includeEmpty is set to true for testing here, but normally in
// UrlEncoded any missing property is just seen as empty anyway, so
// there should be no real difference.
String serialized = UrlEncodeSerializer.Serialize(fbreq, true);
```

Comment: first of all, this looks amazing.
but minor issue, or im forgetting something. but the result im getting after serializing is: 
"access_token=CAADSNVlV9gEBAG32X13ozemPQQGbUFHMCDGO7p8TFrwe588c3KgkhTW64Pzr71tenlTzilBO2glgsaZAwLtCiCsvfbA0lTsyATQb6RPVNOy8twEkoOjinlMnBHnNfmBl6WteUXJze6s1xN3iUhWj2VlB7ZCZAiiD1jvp2IKFTUSZCyTvJk1MAOQSXb5sPpXbwiKyRa6pZAAZDZD&method=post&format=json&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&debug=all&batch=null"
so basically the encoding of brackets and stuff are missing.

Comment: probably because i haven't serialized the batch

Comment: Yeah, you still need to implement the `PrepareData()` method yourself. As I put in comment in the code, you need to fill the `BatchString` property with the json-serialized data from the `Batch` array in there. I assumed you had already figured out how to do the json part...

Comment: amazing jon with the serialization, im still working on this just to perfect it, soon ill send to facebook and hope they will like the payload :0

Comment: Glad you like it! You're kinda lucky; I only know the `Attribute` stuff because at work we use a text message processing system with auto-detection of property types that use it too; it worked with an `Attribute` containing the parser's Type. Only thing I had to really look into was the `p.GetValue(obj, null)` which basically just calls the `get` method of the property.

Comment: i probably miss something because after the whole serialzation process when i decode it (just to see the result facebook will actually get) it still looks not good.
i added HttpUtility.Encode on those & = signs

Comment: The `Encode` function already does the HttpUtility.UrlEncode on all data. All you should need to do is implement `PrepareData()` to fill the `BatchString ` with the json data from `Batch`. Of course, getting that json right is a whole other deal... but there should be plenty of info about that here on SO.

Comment: As a test, you can always just make PrepareData do nothing but `BatchString = "[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]";` to see if that works right. It should, though. Then the real issue is doing that json serialization yourself from the original array.

Comment: you, this PrepareData method works greats, returns exactly what you wrote here.
problem is that facebook still dont like it =\ im starting to hate facebook alil more with each passive second

Comment: Compared to the expected string you posted, there _is_ a "fields" property with value "id,name" missing in your class, though.

Comment: we'll at least now they are telling me i have a problem with batch array! thank you so so much, you did great!

Comment: @OriRefael I fixed this code up a bit; instead of the interface and the `PrepareData()` I just put the Json conversion code in the getter of `BatchString`. This makes it more thread-safe, and less complex.